# How to change the css class of the last cell in every table row?

Tags: jquery, role

My markup looks like this:

```
<div role="row" id="row1grid">
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
</div>
<div role="row" id="row2grid">
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
</div>
<div role="row" id="row3grid">
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
</div>
```

But I would like to use jQuery to change the classname of the last cell in each row:

```
<div role="row" id="row1grid">
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass2"></div>
</div>
<div role="row" id="row2grid">
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass2"></div>
</div>
<div role="row" id="row3grid">
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass"></div>
    <div role="cell" class="myClass2"></div>
</div>
```

I can select all the rows by role, like this:

$("div[role='row']")

But how do I go from there to find the last cell in each row and change its class?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Hank

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
$("div[role='row'] > div:last-child").removeClass('myClass').addClass('myClass2')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q4EWF/)

or

```
$("div[role='row']").children(':last-child').removeClass('myClass').addClass('myClass2')
```

Comment: $("div[role='row'] > div:last-child").removeClass('myClass').addClass('myClass2') seems to work! Thanks a lot both of you

Answer (score 0):

`$("div[role='row'] div:last")` should select the last `div` in the row.

You can then modify the class using:

```
$("div[role='row'] div:last").removeClass('myClass').addClass('myClass2');
```

or

```
$("div[role='row'] div:last")[0].className = "myClass2"
```

Comment: thanks for the very quick reply, but it seems that for instance $("div[role='row'] div:last")[0].className = "myClass2" only changes the class for the cell in the last row

Comment: $("div[role='row'] > div:last-child").removeClass('myClass').addClass('myClass2') seems to work:-)
Thanks a lot both of you